# Assign a priority on subscribers of a Queue using Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, .net-6.0, message-queue, azureservicebus

I know it is possible to assign a priority to messages but this is not what I am looking for, I need to assign a priority to subscribers.

For example, 2 services (A and B) are subscribed on the same queue but I would like to have 1 subscriber (A) at higher priority. This means that service A would process all messages that enter the queue when the 2 services are available, and only when service A is busy then service B would process new messages.

Is that possible using .NET and Azure Service Bus?

### More details:

Each message takes a good amount of time to process (30-60 seconds) so a service is considered busy as soon as it is processing a single message and each service has a single processor.

One subscriber (A) is enough when the message flow is really low (less than 1 message per minute) but when the flow increases, more services (B, C, etc.) will be booted up to satisfy the demand.

I would like to always prioritize service A so it is 100% busy, then use service B if 1 is not enough, then use C if 2 are not enough, etc.

As the demand lowers, I would like to stop the services in the reverse order (C first, then B). For that, subscribers priority is needed, so that C stops receiving messages when 2 services is enough for the current load.

### Edit

Thanks to the current answer, I found out more about Azure Autoscale and the usage of terminate notifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-terminate-notification

This is all great, interesting and of consideration, but I would still like to know the answer to my original question:

> Is it possible to assign a priority on a subscriber, when subscribing to an Azure Service Bus Queue?

Comment: When is Service A busy?  It could be processing 1 message, or 10 messages (depending on how you have configured the fetching mechanism).  Would 10 messages make service A busy?  How many processors does service A have.    I think you need to state why you think this is your problem.  What are you actually trying to do (don't give a solution, explain the problem).

Comment: @Neil thanks for your reply, I added more details to my question

Comment: What is happening during each message processing? Is it querying database (i/o bound) or image processing (CPU bound).  Your service may not be100% utilised, just because it has 1 processor, doesn't mean it's taking 100% of the processing time.

Comment: @Neil The message processing runs a UiPath automation process where the mouse and keyboard are controlled from the program, monopolizing the UI. Therefore, only one program can run at a time on each VM (otherwise they would interfere with each other).

Comment: Service Bus is about competing consumers. There's no priority to consumers. And frankly, I'd advise against order when scaling in/out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify what you mean by the term “service”, but one way to achieve a scalable yet affordable implementation of multiple consuming apps from a queue is to host them in function apps on an app service plan and add a scale out rule based on the queue length to the plan. This is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started

Comment: Thanks! My "service" is a program running a UiPath automation script and so it requires a GUI. Therefore, each instance of my service must be hosted on a separate VM. But this looks promising too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview It seems that a scale out rule based on the queue length could be applied to a VM farm? If so: How does the scale down work more precisely when the queue size is 0? I would not want to shutdown a VM that just picked a message from the queue, currently processing a message

Comment: @Bruno Yes, that looks like the way to go if you’re using VMs

Comment: Is it possible to have some control on which VM to shutdown in priority?

Comment: I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-scale-in-policy#newestvm-scale-in-policy The missing piece now is that I cannot stop a VM anytime, while it is processing a request (and the processing takes 1min to complete). Ideally, a VM would receive a message to be shut down, without doing it right away. It would check first if currently processing a message and if so: Unsubscribe from the queue, wait for the processing to be completed before shutting down, to not ruin a processing that would end in error or incomplete.

Comment: And then I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-terminate-notification Maybe it's the solution? It's getting more and more complex to implement and configure xD

Answer (score 0):

Why not have 2 queues (A & B) and one service.  The service reads each message from queue A until it is empty, then it reads a single message from queue B.  Then go back to checking queue A again.  Repeat.

This means that anything in queue A is given priority.  If something from queue B is being processed, it will complete, but then the higher priority queue will be checked again, before processing another, low priority message.